# Custom user can't access custom modules

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, user-roles

I created a custom module in magento 1.9 which is working fine from the admin part and when I give permission to another admin user to access my module it is visible on top menu but it is showing "Access denied" when I click the menu. I search through many sites but I did not get the right answer.

Points to be noted.

1. Menu is coming when I give permission.
2. I don't have `_isAllowed()` in my module controller. I already tried by creating `_isAllowed()` function and I feel it is useless.
3. here I am mentioning another admin is nothing but a custom role and it is not a default admin role.

Please help me to fix this problem.

My Controller file

```
<?php
class Divum_Pricing_Adminhtml_PricingController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('pricing/pricing');
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
    }
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('pricing/pricing');
    }

    public function updatemetalAction(){
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            $key=1;
            foreach($this->GetAttributeValue('jew_metal') as $metals){
                if(trim($data[$metals['label']])==null || (float)$data[$metals['label']]==0){
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('pricing')->__('Form data must not null or "0"'));
                    $key=0;
                }else{
                    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                    $query = "UPDATE metal_price SET price = '".(float)$data[$metals['label']]."' WHERE metal_name ='".$metals['label']."'";
                    $writeConnection->query($query);
                }
            }

            if($key==1){
                $this->UpdateProductPrice();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('pricing')->__('All the Product Price are updated'.$metal));
            }else{
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('pricing')->__('Product Price is not updated : Please check the form for any error'));
            }

        }else{
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('pricing')->__('Form Data Missing'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    function GetAttributeValue($name) {
        $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
        $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
        $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        return $attributeOptions;
    }

    public function UpdateProductPrice(){
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $product){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
            $value='0';
            $base_price=0;
            $weight=0;
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                if($attributeCode=='jew_metal'){
                    $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                }
                if($attributeCode=='jew_base_price'){
                    $base_price = (float)$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                }
                if($attributeCode=='jew_metal_weight'){
                    $weight = (float)$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                }
            }
            foreach($this->GetAttributeValue('jew_metal') as $metals){
                if($value==$metals['label']){
                    $metalPrice=$this->getMetalPrice($metals['label']);
                    $price=($weight*$metalPrice)+$base_price;
                    $product->setPrice($price)->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getMetalPrice($metalname){
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = "SELECT price FROM metal_price WHERE metal_name = '".$metalname."'";
        return $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine... :) The mistake is in the _isAllowed() function... Thanks Friends.

Comment: show you controller file

Comment: please show adminhtml.xml and config.xml

Comment: With the latest security update from Magento, it is essential for custom modules to have _isAllowed() method in controller files.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried when adding the `_isAllowed()` method. This is probably the issue, although you are doubting that. Maybe there's something wrong in the way you have added it, so please add that code fragment to your question.

Comment: Thanks bro.. You are right :) i made a mistake in my _isAllowed() function.. Now it is working :) ,..... Thank You all :)